# Staggered Grid LayoutManager Stack from end

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, staggered-gridview

I am trying to make a application that displays data in list using `RecyclerView`, In `LinearLayoutManager` there is a option to set Stack from end and reverse layout that allows for me to show the newest data on top of list. Is there anyway I can show the newest data at position 0 (at top) in staggered grid layout?

Answer (score 5):

`StaggeredGridLayoutManager` has the method [setReverseLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html#setReverseLayout(boolean)).

Use it like this:

```
mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(getActivity());
mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GridLayoutManagaer`. In constructor you can pass `true/false` to reverse layout or can use `setReverseLayout(boolean)` method. check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html)

Comment: Yeah, I am using setReverseLayout. All it does it reverse the layout so there is some gap at starting position. I want to show the newest data at first. While stack from end does that action it only supports Linear Layout manager

Comment: @SasiKanth Are you saying, setReverseLayout is only supported by Linear Layout manager ?

Comment: No setreverselayout is supported, but when i use it, it essentially reverses the layout so leaving a blank space for odd number of items at start

Comment: can you try reversing (Sorting based on time stamp) the data model (list of data itself) before updating the staggered grid ?  if you load more data on scroll, you can add at zero index always

Comment: Yeah i have to do the sorting based on tmestamp if i don't want to use reverse layout

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll to the end after updating(inserting) you data (when it's needed)

```
   private void updateData(@NonNull List<Item> items, boolean moveToTheEnd) {
    adapter.updateItems(items);

    if(moveToTheEnd) {
        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount() - 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution that worked for me, without having those spaces at the beginning, is to add this line at the beginning of your onBindViewHolder method in your adapter:

`position = getItemCount()-1-position;`

So your code will be something like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    position = getItemCount()-1-position;

    holder.textView.setText(mObjects.get(position).getText());
}
```